Do temperature variations make trains on Mars impractical?
Train tracks are expected to cope with a variety of temperatures.  They expand and contract over time and seasonal temperatures.
The Martian surface is subject to significantly more temperature variation than Earth - for example, from this document, the ground temperature varies by up to 120 degrees Celsius, summer to winter.
That is significantly wider than the variation you'd expect on Earth, and we have issues with seasonal variations every year... although Mars won't have a problem with leaves on the line...
More focused questions: Can we make a track that could handle the degree of variation? What would the downsides be? Have I missed something that makes it more practical?
Assume real physics and current tech, please.

In many places here on Earth railway tracks have to be designed for a temperature variation of about 70 degrees centigrade (130 degrees Fahrenheit) between the hottest summer day and the coldest winter night...

@AlexP How they manage that sounds like part of a good answer

Agreed. And additionally, consider that we have the power - technological, financial, and will - to not only get humans to Mars but also to build railways. Seems like "we'll figure it out" will be the answer here.

Tracks are possible. And you don't even need new technologies.
120C of temperature difference will give a tensile or compressive stress of about 300 MPa, and steels can have tensile strength in the 400 - 500 MPa range, compared to maybe a third of that for compressive strength.
So all you need to do is have the rails installed so that they have a "neutral temperature," where thermal expansion means they do not experience stress, at the top of the temperature range for the area. When it's hot out, the rail "expands" (but it's constrained so not really, it relaxes) and is under no stress. When it's cold, it tries to contract and experiences tensile stress.
This can be done by installing when the weather is hottest, by using heaters to make it locally hot enough, or by using hydraulics to stretch the steel out if it's cold. Then you weld all the rails together like that. We do this already on Earth.
You will have less of a margin of safety for your rails compared to a 40C variation like on Earth. This means the rails will snap more often as they contract from cold.
You could try mitigating the problem by alloying the steel with other materials. For example, invar has a thermal expansion coefficient of about 10% most steels, (1.5 um/mK compared to 15-20 for most steels) while still being relatively strong. If your civilization can get enough nickel (it literally a third nickel and you don't get much in the way of benefits at lower ratios) that's an option.
In addition, you can use joints. Modern designs that mitigate the maintenance problems associated with flat joints will allow you to reduce your neutral temperature a bit and have a little expansion of the rails.

Worth noting that the reduced gravity means less weight being born by the rails, which ought to make it easier to find a suitable alloy since it won't need to be as strong.

Don't weld the rails. it makes them more vulnerable to expansion and contraction damage from temperature. https://trid.trb.org/View/1375765#:~:text=The%20main%20disadvantage%20of%20continuously,longitudinal%20displacements%20of%20the%20track.

Practical Engineering has a really good video on this on Earth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqmOSMAtadc .

@DWKraus You don't want jointed track though. From the same page: "continuous welded rail [is] one of the basic preconditions for the introduction of high speed services"

breather switches, AKA tapered expansion joints for rail also exist. they don't have the problems of gaps so they work for high speed rail. generally you have several welded sections then one breather to allow for some expansion and contraction.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breather_switch

@Bergi You WANT them, but they won't work on Mars. That doesn't mean you can't have slower trains, or come up with an alternative design that compensates.

Good steels have tensile strengths in the 1-2 GPa range. 400-500 is basic carbon steel. Even S690QL (700 MPa) has almost no alloying elements.

@Bergi High speed rail is overrated. I'd rather have a low speed rail system that gets me everywhere, then a high speed rail system that gets me nowhere. High speed rail costs about 200 million per mile, will probably be astronomically more expensive in space ;). Lower Gravity -> significantly easier to derail, as trains rely on gravity to stay on the track.

Additionally mars is a bit more bumpy than the earth... Whose topography makes long distance high speed rail un affordable... Mars it will be even more so.

@Questor DWKraus I wasn't sure what the OP was aiming for. Even at lower speeds, CWR has advantages like higher strength, requiring less maintenance, and causing less wear on the wheels. And as this answer shows, tensile strength of steel is high enough for CWR to work fine on Mars. Gravity should not a problem either, if anything you'd just have higher axle loads (in mass, for same weight) on a similar build. I think harder problems would be caused by topography and sandstorms.

With less gravity you could probably make it out of something other than steel too.

Before we consider track expansion, it may be worth thinking what sort of track we are using.
Mars has about a third the gravity on Earth. A train will have the same mass and momentum as on Earth, but the weight will be a third, and the limiting frictional grip on the rails will be a third too. This means the train will be less able to climb hills, or come to a halt. Maglev trains do not have this limit. In emergencies, you can turn down the maglev, and use a larger breaking surface between the bottom of the train and the track.
The train will not be fighting atmospheric resistance, as trains do on Earth. The train could travel a lot faster. It is hard to know what the overall energy budget might be, but assuming the maglev suspension takes some power even if the train is still, there will be some best way of travelling between A and B that minimises the total energy used in the suspension and the acceleration.
Maglev trains can have expansion gaps.
Why is there a railway? Is it for moving people and their luggage, or for shifting large amounts of freight? If you want to shift tens of thousands of tons of ore slowly, and there are no great hills to climb, you can modify the locomotives to grip conventional rails or add rack-and-pinion on the difficult spots. There is an article on Wikipedia on Longest Trains, which may give some hints. Some of these trains run through deserts with large Mars-like differences in temperature between night and day.

Purpose is moving large masses of material that aren't pressure or temperature sensitive.  Long distance people travel should always be by redundant convoy.  A derail would risk passengers as no alternate vehicles; break one transit rover, get in spare

For the safety purposes you can attach magnetic brakes to the bogeys that will stick to the rail directly hwen braking. Some trams have this as an emergency brake.

Why would the train be less able to climb hills? Sure, it has only a third of the maximum friction with the rails, but it also only needs a third of the force to climb the hill, so IMO it should cancel out..

@Tomeamis hills are also bigger on mars

@Yakk as in steeper? Because if a train can climb a, say, 5 degree slope, it can climb a 5 degree hill whether it's 20 meters or 2000 meters high.

@Tomeamis Yes, or so I thought.  But https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2011JE003865 seems to indicate it is more complex than I thought.

@Yakk Sure, the stability of an irregular pile of irregular particles is a more complex problem than the problem of maintaining static friction between a regularly-shaped wheel and a regularly-shaped rail. And for precisely that reason, I don't think the conclusions about effects of gravity carry over from one problem to the other.

The solution is simple: Just include expansion joints (known as Breather Switches in railway parlance) in the rails.
The diagonal joint between separate rails will allow a significant amount of expansion and contraction without sun kinks, and without large gaps between rails that will result in noise and vibration.

it is a cargo line

@Yakk It doesn't matter whether it's a cargo or a passenger line, vibration is a bad thing, and is going to result in unnecessary wear.

Prerequisite
Even though the question states "current tech", I take a running Mars economy (several "cities", industry etc.) for granted here, making all necessary materials, tools, work-force etc. available on the spot. Not so much any kind of terra/mars-forming or atmosphere building has to have taken place.
Material Magic
You do not need to build train tracks of plain steel. There are also high-tech materials like graphene or other meta-materials which might serve as track.
Mono Magic
You can also build a non-wheeled train. Like a monorail magnetic levitating train (MagLev).
Hyper Magic
If feasible you can also employ the concept of a Hyperloop. Meaning some tubes in which the train is running. Those tunnels could be temperature-controlled to even accommodate steel tracks. Mostly you would use such tubes for evading atmosphere drag which is not so much of a problem on Mars. But the tubes would also help against the Mars sand/dust covering the tracks for example.
Metro Magic
You could also put all tracks undergrounds, like in a Mars Metro. The temperature differences are much less of a problem there, because there is no sunlight for heating up everything. Can be combined with the other concepts as well.

There were a couple of depictions of a tube train on Mars on the TV series "Babylon 5". Not too much about how it worked.

Some local industry is required for any rail solution, but large deployment of advanced meta materials is significantly harder than steel.  Pure subway would increase cost by more than an order of magnitude!  Rail was supposed to be the quick and easy option

Why wouldn't plain steel work? We did place several pieces of machinery on Mars, made of ordinary materials, and they worked just fine. @user2702772: Rail is never the quick and easy option. Railways are expensive. The quick and easy option is always a dirt road.

Rail on earth contracts by >1cm with 40 degree gaps.  On Mars, rail heated by sunlight might well reach temperatures somewhat above local local ground - try touching steel in sunlight!  The document I linked to for environment data is actually on the mars rovers, and details how marginal their operation actually is. Thermally\power wise the Moxie experiment was a challenge.  And they crawl along at metres per day.  Rail between industrial sites - that's going to be harder than expected.

@user2702772: Ye olde skoole rails contract. Modern continuous welded rails don't. It is perfectly possible to fix a rail so that it does not contract; yes this will create a tension in the rail, just like in a rod supporting a weight, but calculating the necessary strength of steel rods has been a solved problem for hundreds of years. Here is a YouTube video explaining how continuous welded rails work.

@user2702772: if costs explode but you get a feasible solution for that, you have to rethink the terms of being costly against not having a solution at all. "Cheap" does not imply "low numbers" in terms of costs automatically, it just demands "the lowest cost of a solution". From what you mentioned, sounds like the Hyperloop is the way to go for you as best compromise (it does not need to be evacuated on Mars because of the almost non-existing atmosphere). It can be seen as an "overground" Metro tube - combining the best of all worlds.

@AlexP that works on earth with a deltaT of ~40 C... It doesn't work so well on mars with a delta T > 140 C.

@Questor: In most places in the temperate zone railroad rails are designed for a temperature difference of some 70 to 80 °C between the coldest winter night and the hottest summer day, specifically between −10 °C or −20 °C and about 60 °C. (Rails get much hotter than the air.) Doubling the width of the temperature interval will only double the tension in the rails, still well within the strength of the material.
